# Play music in background and only stop in certain instances

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, video, background-audio

I have an app that shows videos in a timeline. The videos autoplay and by default they should be silent. If the user is playing music in the background, music should not stop at this time. It is only when tapping the video that it should actually pause the background music and let the video play. And once the video is done playing, the user's previous audio should continue where it left off.

I've tried using

`[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];`

but this lets the music mix with the audio even if the video is in full screen mode. Of course, I could ensure that when the play button is tapped, the music pauses, but that might not be the cleanest solution.

Any better ideas?